# Where to read about programming?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm a programmer for some time now yet I haven't found the right websites which offer me the information I'm interested in. I've looked at TechCrunch, Slashdot, etc. but there wasn't so much actually about programming.

- When something urgently important happens in the programming world, where could I read it first?
- What are some good sites/communities around programming?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

- [reddit - programming](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/)
- [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/) - Although this is not strictly programming

Answer (score 4):

There are a billion, i would first start with [XKCD](http://xkcd.com) to start your day off right.

I would have reccomended [Joel On Software](http://joelonsoftware.com), but he has moved on.  There are still **plenty** of articles to read on that site.

Ever since Joel stopped writing I have turned to [SlashDot](http://slashdot.org) as well as [TechRepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/)

Answer (score 2):

> When something urgently important
>   happens in the programming world,
>   where could I read it first?

I doubt that there's a CNN for all of "programming".  Maybe the reason that you haven't found it is that it doesn't really exist or your expectations need calibration.

> What are some good sites/communities
>   around programming?

I would say you're posting at one of the best.

Comment: The problem is that SO is pretty much limited to Q&A :)

Comment: But it's all about programming.  Isn't that your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Well you're on a good one already, StackOverflow.

Have a look on [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com) that's good.

Answer (score 0):

I generally like http://www.reddit.com/r/programming and http://news.ycombinator.com/

Also, if you're interested in copyright and IP concerns in the programming world, http://www.arstechnica.com is generally good there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use:

http://channel9.msdn.com/

It is obviously geared towards developers using Microsoft Products but the plethora of different articles and videos is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DZone](http://www.dzone.com/links/) to keep up-to-date with the latest programming trends. It's similar to Reddit but has a better selection of links for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

for news on coding, technology, design and stuff like that, i can recommend www.newtnetnews.com