# Is there a good, frequently updated, well written news site for c# developers preferably with a alt.net bent

Tags: c#

I would love to visit a web site and catch up on the latest **C# news**, Microsoft Framework and other alt.net news.

Is there something out there that offers a bit of editorial or is aggregating blog feeds into Google reader the only solution.

The only thing that I'm aware of that comes close to my requirements is:

- [DotnetKicks](http://dotnetkicks.com/default.aspx)  - lack of editorial, no ability to customise a home page to filter interests to create pseudo editorial
- [Visual C# Developer Center - Team and Community Blogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vcsharp/ee677534.aspx) - again no real editorial

### Related posts

- [Where to read about programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892753/where-to-read-about-programming) (Not c# specific)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found [The Morning Brew](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/) to be extremely informative.

Comment: thanks ben looks, this is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

Following is not a news site but a perfectly managed and up-to-date Blog-come-News site for **C# / .Net Developers**. You will get updates about every new bit in `.Net / C# world` by `Chris Alcock` but from Monday to Friday only.

One of the links I never miss to keep me updated. Check it your self

**[The Morning Brew :
Software | Information | Community](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/)**